# Как в AngularJs + ui-router загружать шаблон сразу после загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Существует сайт с роутингом от первого еще Ангуляра.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'default.html'
    })
    .state('second', {
        url: '/second',
        templateUrl: 'second.html'
    })
    .state('third', {
        url: '/third',
        templateUrl: 'third.html'
    })
    .state('faq', {
        url: '/faq',
        templateUrl: 'faq.html'
    })
    .state('deals', {
        url: '/deals',
        templateUrl: 'deals.html'
    })
});
```

Суть проблемы в том, что на сайте присутствуют ссылки не только типа `ui-sref`, но и обычные `<a href="#">`. Чтобы обеспечить их работоспособность дефолтный путь всех ссылок выставлен как `''`. При загрузке страницы, естественно, не загружается первый шаблон - home, default.html.

Выставляя для `home` такой `url`: `''`, т.е. пустую строку, страница загружается так, как должна, но внутренние ссылки не с `ui-sref` перекидывают на домашнюю страницу.

Как решить эту проблему? При загрузке страницы должен загрузиться первый шаблон, а ссылки не с `ui-sref` должны остаться работоспособными.

Comment: попробуй сделать [mcve] с примерами ссылок и таких и таких, чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть проблему. Отредактировав сниппет или на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Выставьте нормальный путь `otherwise('/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Нужен синтаксис такого рода:
`ui-sref="state({'#':'anchor'})"`

AngularJs 1.6.4
///
ui-router 1.0.3